# How to send the value from api to the handleSubmit in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I can not figure out how to send the value from api to the handleSubmit function and merge the value into the inputs value that is made from handleChange function.

For example, I can successfully send a input value that is being written on the textarea by using onChange event to the function handleChange in order to send it to the db by using axios.post.

```
import { useState, useEffect, React } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ListUser() {

const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);
const {id} = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
}, []);

function getUser() {
    axios.get(`https://xxxxxxx/api_xxxx/users/${id}`).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        setUsers(response.data);
    });
}

const handleChange = (event) => {        
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value}));    
}

const handleSubmit = (event) => {       
    event.preventDefault();     
    axios.post(`https://xxxxxxxx/api_xxxxxxx/user/save`, inputs).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
    });          
}

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <textarea type="text" name="comment" onChange={handleChange} />

    {Object.values(users).map((user, key) =>    
    {user.id}
    )} 
    <button type="submit"}>Register</button>
    </form>
)
}
```

I also need to send the value from api,"{user.id}" to the same db alongside with above comment by using axios.post. Could anyone please teach me how to send the value from api,"{user.id}" to handleSubmit and merge the value into inputs so that I can send both comment and id to the same table of the db?

I tried to send it to handleChange by using onSubmit event like below, but nothing happend.

By the way, if I, for a testing purpose, use "input type="text" name="id" onChange={handleChange}" and type the id in the input box, the value can be reached to the expeceted table successfully. However I should not use input box as well as onChange here.

```
{Object.values(users).map((user, key) =>    
    <input type="hidden" value={user.id} name="id" onSubmit={handleChange} />
)}
```

api:(post)

DbConnect.php

```
<?php

    class DbConnect {
        private $server = 'xxxxxx';
        private $dbname = 'xxxxx';
        private $user = 'xxxxx';
        private $pass = 'xxxxxx';

        public function connect() {
            try {
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$this->server .';dbname=' 
. $this->dbname, $this->user, $this->pass);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
 PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $conn;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo "Database Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    
    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");

include 'DbConnect.php';
$objDb = new DbConnect;
$conn = $objDb->connect();

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
switch($method) {
case "POST":    
$user = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments(id, parent_id, comment, created_at, 
updated_at) VALUES(null, :parent_id, :comment, :created_at, 
:updated_at)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$created_at = date('Y-m-d');
$updated_at = date('Y-m-d');
    
$stmt->bindParam(':parent_id', $user->id);
$stmt->bindParam(':comment', $user->comment);
$stmt->bindParam(':created_at', $created_at);
$stmt->bindParam(':updated_at', $updated_at);

if($stmt->execute()) {
            $response = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Record created 
successfully.'];
        } else {
            $response = ['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Failed to create 
record.'];
        }
echo json_encode($response);
break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Here, `{Object.values(users).map((user, key) =>    
    <input type="hidden" value={user.id} name="id" onSubmit={handleChange} />
)} ` in this `onSubmit` needs to change into `onChange` because inputs only consists of `onChange` to change value and `button` consists of `onSubmit` to send value

Comment: you forgot to add return in this `{Object.values(users).map((user, key) =>    
    <input type="hidden" value={user.id} name="id" onSubmit={handleChange} />
)} ` it should be like this `{Object.values(users).map((user, key) =>  {  
    return (<input type="hidden" value={user.id} name='id' onSubmit={handleChange} />)} )} `

Comment: nuser137, Thank you for your comment. I tried {Object.values(users).map((user, key) =>  {       return (<input type="hidden" value={user.id} name='id' onSubmit={handleChange} />)} )}, but it shows an empty white screen when I open the page.

Comment: could you please post a runnable script, so I could understand the issue more?  And extremely sorry, when I was posting a comment then I didn't change `<input type="hidden" value={user.id} name='id' onChange={handleChange} />` it should be onChange not onSubmit.

Comment: and please mention what API you are using in your code.

Comment: nuser137, I have update the script. I am using php.  I guess that I have to pass {user.id} to handleSubmit and merge it into inputs. Maybe I should not use input onChange.

Comment: first you should read this doc https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input and in react onChange is needed whenever we want to change value but probably I know there is another way to send value and you saw white screen for that reason that there is "axios error" when you inspect your page.

Comment: nuser137, Thank you. This page is user's comment page. {user.id} is not something user should change and I have to implement that the system automatically can send to the db. Since I can send the value to the db with <input type="text" name="id" onChange={handleChange} /> by actually typing the id for testing purpose, I don't think there is something wrong with axios or api setting.

Comment: So, are you able to send value? Are you getting any white screen if so, then inspect your page any error if you're  getting please let me know.

Comment: nuser137, Thank you. Yes, I can send the value to the same table with comment by actually typing the id which I used <input type="text" name="id" onChange={handleChange} />. I am not getting white screen with the setting I posted and I am not getting any error.

Comment: Then, I think almost your issue is solved right??

Comment: nuser137, No. I need to set up this react script so that the system can automatically send the api value {user.id} to the db instead of using <input type="text" name="id" onChange={handleChange} />.

Comment: could you please post a runnable PHP script (backend) to your question so taking help of it I could set react script?